# Sticky sidebar in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I must prepare a site with sticky sidebar.

Link to this page: http://iem.pw.edu.pl/~witkowr1/cwiczenie1/menu.html

In this subpage I try make sticky image Validator and it's not work.
I sent example code:

```
function fixDiv() {
    var $cache = $('#validator');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) $cache.css({
        'position': 'fixed',
            'top': '10px',
            'right': '40px'
    });
    else $cache.css({
        'position': 'absolute',
            'top': '75px',
            'right': '40px'
    });
}
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
fixDiv();
```

But my main problem is sticky menu and I don't have any idea.

Comment: Why not give your "sticky" div fixed positioning in the first place?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do. You have the validator center on the top of the page, on scroll (after 100px) you remove it from the flow, making it fixed and if it's less than 100px you make it absolute... So what you are trying to do... make the validator sticky from the start, or you want to return it at the starting position when you scroll < 100px ?? It's not clear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving your '#menu' div these styles:

```
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: -20px;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
```

Also, you might want to remove the overflow:hidden from the body element.